# Need help configuring join messages on my Discord bot

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember, channel, message) => {
guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ew"));
    embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("User Join Notification")
        .setDescription(guildMember.username + " has joined this server.")
        .setColor("#21a1e1")
    guildMember.guild.channels.get('430681100956991511').send(embed);
});
```

Whenever a player joins the server, it will display *undefined has joined this server* rather than their actual username.

How could I rectify this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from [the Discord.JS doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), `guildMember` doesn't have a `username` but it has a `user` object which itself contains a `username`.

```
.setDescription(guildMember.user.username + " has joined this server.")
```

Alternatively, `guildMember.nickname` could be used but it would work only if the `guildMember` has configured one, so it will still display undefined sometimes.